# NSLayoutConstraint constant changed callback

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nslayoutconstraint

I have UIView which contains an UIWebview. The UIView has leading and trailing constraints (20pt). Now if the UIWebview get zoomed in which I detect via UIScrollViewDelegate:scrollViewDidZoom, I set the constant of the constraints to 0pt. And if I scroll out, I will reverse the behaviour and set the constant of the constraints to the old value (20pt).

The problem is that after the UIWebview is resized it still has the old zoomScale, which I need to set programatically to to right value. But for that I need to wait until the UIWebview is resized. Is there something like a callback which tells me that my UIWebview has it's new size and I can set the right zoomScale?

At the moment I do all this in an UIViewController but I also could encapsulate the UIView in an custom view.

Answer (score 1):

*You have to use the below method I have mentioned, this is called whenever your view controller needs to update its layout.*

---

1. `(void)updateViewConstraints` selector of UIViewController.
2. `(void)updateConstraints` selector of UIView if you have extended said view.

---

*But don't forget to call [super updateViewConstraints] in this method otherwise it will crash.*